# Returning pointer to template function instantiation from constexpr function

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, function-pointers, constexpr

I've been digging through cppreference, but I cannot figure out why the code below does not compile. Can anybody enlighten me?

```
template<typename T, T a> void g();
typedef void(*Func)();
Func f;

template<typename T>
constexpr Func get(T a)
{
   return g<T, a>;
}

void set()
{
   f = get(1);
}
```

I'm compiling with something like

```
g++ -c -Wall -Werror -std=gnu++11
```

Comment: [constexpr function parameters as template arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26582875/3953764)

Comment: The error message, is it unreadable?  Or is this an existential "why?"  What level of reason is causing confusion?