# Expand function argument pack as a non-type parameter pack argument?

Tags: c++

Why doesn't the following compile:

```cpp
template <int...is> void g() {}

template <typename...Ts> void f(Ts...ts) {
    g<ts...>();
}

int main() {
    f(1,2);
}
```

it fails with

```
error: no matching function for call to 'g<ts#0, ts#1>()'
|     g<ts...>();
|     ~~~~~~~~^~
```

I understand that in general this is not possible since `f` can be called with anything.

I am curious if there is a way to make this work in cases such as here where the compiler clearly sees the compile time constant arguments in the call to `f`?

Comment: The parameters of a function are not constant expressions, so they are not usable in a template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable number of arguments in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c)

Comment: Template parameters must be known at compile time, not run time.

Comment: Also, this might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/ellipses-and-variadic-templates?view=msvc-160

Comment: Does this answer your question? [constexpr function parameters as template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582875/constexpr-function-parameters-as-template-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

There is this way to do it:

```cpp
f(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{}, std::integral_constant<int, 2>{});

// Or your own structs
template<int V>
struct i_t {
    constexpr operator int() const { return V; }
};

template<int V>
inline constexpr i_t<V> i;

f(i<1>, i<2>);
```

Since `std::integral_constant<T, N>::operator T()` just returns `N` so is a constant expression, and when you have `g<ts...>`, it calls `operator int` on each argument in the pack, which doesn't use the value of any `ts`.

Comment: A good one, thanks @Artyer.  Is "when you have g<ts...>, it calls operator int on each argument in the pack" specified by the standard somewhere (like calling the ctor of T with the argument, the pack in this case)?

Comment: @giik A non-type template argument should be a "converted constant expression" of the type of the template-parameter (here, `int`) (see: [temp.arg.nontype]p2), and a converted constant expression can be implicitly converted using user-defined conversions (see: [expr.const]p(10.1)). So there is an implicit conversion and it is used

Answer (score 0):

You can only use typename or class with parameter packs, so int s wont work. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

There are ways to only make f work for only ints though, I made this example for you. If you have any questions let me know.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// Create a constexpr (evaluated at compile time) to check
// if all arguments are ints.
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr bool are_all_ints()
{
    // conjunction is a 'logical and' when doing template metaprogramming
    // is_same checks the types , the syntax is what it is to expand for all template parameters
    return std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<int, Ts>...>;
}

// now you can either use a static assert to give a compile time warning
template <typename... Ts>
void g(Ts&&... values)
{
    static_assert(are_all_ints<Ts...>(), "this function only works with ints");
}

// or you can chose to completely hide the function
// f2 for anything that doesn't have all ints.
template <typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<are_all_ints<Ts...>(), void> g2(Ts&&... values)
{
}

template <typename... Ts>
void f(Ts&&... ts)
{
    g(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

template <typename... Ts>
void f2(Ts&&... ts)
{
    g2(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

int main()
{
    f(1, 2);
    //f(1.0, 2.0);
    //f2(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

Comment: *You can only use typename or class with parameter packs, so int s wont work.* this is totally false.  The first syntax in your link even has *A non-type template parameter pack with an optional name*

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed defining template<int... ts> f() is allowed, and then make instances like f<1,2,3>(), And you can expand the ts... in the body like initializing a vector with it : std::vector<int> v{ts...}; ). But expanding those ints as actual parameters to the function won't work. void f(ts... values), that will not compile